# Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type parameter declared in array type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at call of method `slice`

Tags: flowtype

I have a simple js example where I'm getting a weird inferred error.

Missing type annotation for `T`. `T` is a type parameter declared in  array type [1] and was implicitly instantiated at  call of method `slice` [2].Flow(InferError)

```js
function getChunk(items: Array<Object>, start: number, end: number): Array<Object> {
  const chunk = items.slice(start, end)
  return chunk
}
```

I'm unsure why it's trying to infer the array even though I did express it as an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here's the head scratcher.

The error was displayed before I had entered the return type of `Array<Object>` so the error was a bit weird and didn't express to me that the return type was missing.

But it was not until I relaunched the editor when the return type was accepted. So maybe the flow server was hung or something.